# Common words in two strings found, but need commas... no regex if possible

Tags: javascript

I would like to see the common words separated by commas...

https://jsbin.com/qafixed/1/edit?js,console

```
let first = ["hello", "hurray", "world", "fee"];
let second = ["hello", "earth", "fee", "hurray"];
let res = "";

for (let i=0; i<first.length; i++) {
  for (let j=0; j<second.length; j++) {
    if (first[i] == second[j]) {
      res = res + first[i]
    }
  }
}

console.log(res)
// ---> output: "hellohurrayfee"

//  -----> expected output: "hello, hurray, fee"
```

Comment: And the problem/question is?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
let first = ["hello", "hurray", "world", "fee"];
let second = ["hello", "earth", "fee", "hurray"];

let res = first.filter(x => second.includes(x)).join(', ');
console.log(res)
```

or just add a separator like below if you want to follow your double loop approach

```
res += res !== "" ? ( ", " + first[i] ) : first[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added a small fix in your code.I have updated my answer, check it.

```js
        let first = ["hello", "hurray", "fee", "world"];
        let second = ["hello", "earth", "fee", "hurray"];
        let dupl = [];
        
        let res = "";
        
        for (let i=0; i<first.length; i++) {
          for (let j=0; j<second.length; j++) {
            if (first[i] == second[j]) {
                dupl.push(first[i]);
            }
          }
        }
        
        for (let i=0;i < dupl.length;i++){

            res += (i == dupl.length-1) ? dupl[i] : dupl[i]+", ";
        }
        
        document.write(res);
```

Comment: Thank you guys for taking your time to enlighten me, some real teachers are lurking here... Special thanks to #Marios Nikolaou, who put some extra lines into my own code, it helped a lot.

Comment: Well, I have stuck into another problem. My bad, I was not clear with the initial task. So I need a code that works with any two arrays (and with any strings in them in random order). I have changed the string order in the code above and it does not work, obviously, I get an extra comma after the last element. Sry again, my bad.  Any ideas...? :)

Comment: @eddie what is the problem?

Comment: If I change the word order in an array the code puts an extra comma after the last word. For example: let first = ["hello", "hurray", "fee", "world"], then the output will be: "hello, hurray, fee, " I am aware it should be a function, but I still can't get rid of the extra comma. :)

Comment: @eddie check it now.

Comment: Sir, it is now perfect (it was before too, only my describing was not). Thank you!

Comment: I can because I must... But it does not satisfy me, however I can learn from it. :)

Comment: @ Marios Nikolaou Can I ask you something somewhere more private? If you don't mind. I can't find a proper section for that here.

Comment: @eddie i don't know how to start private chat

Comment: @ Marios Nikolaou Me neither and it seems to be impossible. Never mind, it is not a question of life and death, see you around here hopefully. :)